# Database record value as Radiobutton value?

Tags: database, vb.net, vba

I know this is quite vague but,
is it possible to set a radiobuttons value from input from a database record.
I am creating a quiz system on visual basic and I am wondering if I could import a field from a database table and put it in as the radiobutton's text?

Any further info needed please tell me, I know it's vague but I just want to know if it is worth trying.
Thanks

Comment: _In today's world, we all live with the burden of feeling that anything is possible if we're only clever enough, smart enough, work hard enough. -Elizabeth McGovern_ In short. It's possible. :D

Comment: Haha what a wonderful answer. Could you tell me how?

Comment: I can give you something to start on. Not the code but the logic. Is  the number of choices fixed or depends on how many choices you want?

Comment: the number of choices is fixed to 3

Comment: VBA or VB.Net? You've tagged both.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the logic.

Since the choices are fixed to 3 then make 3 ***RadioButtons***.

In the database, make a table for ***Questions*** and a table for ***Answers*** connecting the two tables with an ID of your choice.

In the Answers table, make 3 fields: ***Answer1, Answer2 and Answer3*** (or how you want to name the choices).

In the ***Questions*** table, add a field for, ofcourse, the ***Question***, the ***QuestionID*** and a field determining the ***Answer***.

Now in .NET's side,
Populate/Change the 3 ***RadioButtons***' text to the 3 choices coming from the Answers table. Ex. ***RadioButton1 is for Answer1, RadioButton2 is for Answer2 and RadioButton3 for Answer3***.

Getting the **SELECTED** Answer:

```
 Public AnswerStr as String
 Private Sub RadioButtons_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged, RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
       AnswerStr = RadioButton1.Text
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
       AnswerStr = RadioButton2.Text
    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
       AnswerStr = RadioButton3.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, to know the right answer, query the ***Questions*** table like this:

```
"Select Count(*) from Questions Where QuestionID = '" varQuestionID "' and Answer = '" & AnswerStr & "'"
```

If the result of that query is greater than zero then the answer is CORRECT, else, the answer is WRONG.